# How to get contact name from recipient_id?

Tags: android

I was developing an SMS application, want wanted to show the Contact name in MainActivity, I was using:

```
 Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
```

as

```
 Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");
```

throws null exception in Samsung devices.

Code:

```
 //Log.v(LOGTAG, "Trying to get messgaes");
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
            //Log.v(LOGTAG, "Linking to mesages");
            //Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            //Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");

            //Log.v(LOGTAG, "Executing cursor");
            Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(uriSMSURI, projection, null, null, "date DESC limit 10");
            //Log.v(LOGTAG, "Messages query executed");
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                String recipient_id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("recipient_ids"));
                Integer message_count = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("message_count"));

                String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                final String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"));
                final String date = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
                final Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);

                //Log.v(LOGTAG, "Msg: " + body + " from: " + address);
                address = address.trim();
                String addressOriginal;
                if (address.toString().startsWith("92")) {
                    address = address.toString().replace("92", "0");
                } else if (address.toString().startsWith("3")) {
                    address = "0" + address;
                } else if (address.toString().startsWith("+92")) {
                    address = address.toString().replace("+92", "0");
                }
                final String nAdd = address;
                time = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getApplicationContext());
                if (time) {
                    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy k:mm");
                } else {
                    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a");
                }
                //String usr = getContactName(getApplicationContext(), nAdd);
                Messages msg = new Messages();
                msg.setThreadID(id);
                msg.setRecipientID(recipient_id);
                msg.setMessageCount(message_count);
                msg.setMessage(body);
                msg.setAddress(address);
                msg.setTime(dateFormat.format(timestamp));
                msg.setTimeStamp(timestamp);
                String num = GetContactData(recipient_id); //Returns wrong number
                msg.setSenderName(num);



                msgList.add(msg);                        

            }

            return "done";
```

GetContactData Function:

```
    public String GetContactData(String id)
{
    String number = null;
    Cursor phones = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, null, null);
    if(phones.moveToFirst())
    {
        number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }
    phones.close();
    return number;
}
```

This function is returning wrong number, I've tried to get the contact name too but it returns wrong name as well, How can I get the correct contact name from recipient_id?

Comment: Solved the problem  from this: http://www.projsolution.com/a105-84564-java

Code:

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem  from this: http://www.projsolution.com/a105-84564-java